# WordPress website loads more posts than expected

Tags: posts, themes, query-posts, sql

On the homepage of a WordPress website the latest posts are visible. In the dashboard it's set to display 10 posts on the home page.

However, it loads 133 posts.
Switching to the default theme didn't make any difference.

The version of WordPress is updated.

Where should we start debugging the problem?

Comment: Start by disabling all your plugins and see if the issue still exists

Comment: @swissspidy Thanks! Totally forgot about that technique

Comment: @swissspidy Disabled all. It doesn't make any change.

Comment: @DHL17 Sorry, what code? That's what I'm asking: I have no idea where to start debugging this. Changing the theme to default and disabling the plugins didn't make *any* change.

Comment: ok. which theme u r using currently?

Answer (score 2):

The theme is most likely altering the main query via the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook, chaning the `posts_per_page` argument to -1 for all posts, or another higher number.

You can search your theme folder for `pre_get_posts` to see all the times this hook is used.

A better solution would be to install the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/). With this plugin installed and active, you get a wealth of information about each page request.

To use it, login as admin and visit your homepage once the plugin is active. The admin bar will have a new options. Click the new option (looks like a bunch of numbers) and choose the "Hooks & Actions" section. From there, select "Pre" from the "Hook" dropdown and it will list all where the `pre_get_posts` hooks is being called.

[image: query monitor hooks and actions section]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But even when using the default theme, the problem persists. Query Monitor looks like a useful plugin.

Comment: The "Queries" section of Query Monitor will allow you to see the SQL for the main query. Sometime looking at that can provide clues to what might be altering it.

Comment: IIRC you can also see the stack trace of the queries